# Having a little problem with folding nested lists

Tags: haskell

So I'm trying to write a function that folds a custom data type which is basically just a nested list. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here's what I have so far.

```
data MyTree a = Node a [MyTree a] deriving (Show, Read, Eq)  

foldMT :: MyTree a -> [a]
foldMT (Node x) = [x]
foldMT (MyTree x) = concatMap foldMT x
```

I get the following error. It's referring to the last statement of foldMT.

> Not in scope: data constructor `MyTree'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because `MyTree` is not a constructor. Your fold instead needs to be something like:

```
foldMT (Node x ts) = x : concatMap foldMT ts
```

Comment: I will, I just have to wait a few more minutes before it will let me ;)